# What's the right way to block brute force of HTTP basic auth?

Tags: brute-force-attacks

Here's my thought,

Set a threshold like 30 times in a minute, then block this IP for a few minutes.

But If the attacker forge the source IP address, this could block legitimate user immediately.

And I'm confused now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a common way to block brute forces on all types of services, including http basic auth is [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/). Bots can't forge a source IP address for a full TCP connection(in your case a HTTP request), you don't have to worry about that. (see [Are IP addresses "trivial to forge"?](https://serverfault.com/questions/90725/are-ip-addresses-trivial-to-forge) )

Comment: AFAIK, _fail2ban_ scans logs for offending IP addresses. I'm gonna google it up, but for other googlers... it would be nice to read abou it right here: when does it do so? Periodically? Or constantly monitoring the log stream? So, does it get triggered by suspicious activity real-time, as the attack happens, or does it ban the IP when it gets a go of reading the logs, _after the fact_? Thx.